# BigCommerce Footer Script Trouble

Tags: javascript, footer, bigcommerce

I got this script from a developer to add to my BigCommerce footer to block buyers from selecting the Russian Federation as a shipping country on our website. Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
var countries = new Array("Russian Federation");

var i = 0;
var lng = countries.length;

$('.ExpressCheckoutContent').ajaxSuccess(function(){
    for(i = 0; i < lng; i++)
    {
        $('#FormField_11 option').each(function(){
            if($(this).text().search(countries[i]) >= 0)
            {
                $(this).remove();
            };
        });
    }
})
//]]></script>
```

As of right now Russia is still showing as an option on the website. I'm an absolute beginner so I have no idea what I should be looking for in terms of issues.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey Megan, could you share a link to your site?

Comment: Judging by the code formatting, the developer is not very professional :) (edited it for you). Now, to help you we should see the relevant bits of html, so please either add a link to the site like Karen has suggested (actually, this is not a recommended way at StackOverflow) or open dev tools (ctrl+shift+I in most browsers on Windows), open "Elements" tab, find an element with class="ExpressCheckoutContent" (there can be multiple) and post its content. The most probable reason is: something has changed and there's either no `.ExpressCheckoutContent` or no `#FormField_11 option` element

Answer (score 0):

You need after the end of ajax call to run one line

```
$("#FormField_11[value='Russian Federation']").remove();
```

This will remove any option from the select with id #FormField_11 with value of "Russian Federation"